# Getting user data from Azure AD in a Blazor WASM application

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I would like to get not just the name of the authenticated user but username, email data, too.
I use these lines in components but it gives back only the name of user:

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;
    var name = user.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user object is of type ClaimsPrincipal. You can find all the claims in the Claims property of the user.

More information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

If there are claims missing, you might be able to add these as optional claims in the app registration.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I solved it on the server side with the help of Microsoft Graph. It was not easy. I tried the Claims but I did not get all the information what I wanted.

Comment: If there are claims missing, you might be able to add these as optional claims in the app registration. I updated my answer.